# Rails: How to force a form to post rather than patch?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a form for creating tasks which is displayed on both projects/show and tasks/show.

The form on projects/show creates new tasks fine, but on tasks/show it wants to edit the task, since I need to call the task ID from within the show action of my tasks controller.

I need to modify this form to always create new tasks.

I tried `method: post` but rails still inserts `<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch" />` into the HTML.

Here are my controllers and the form:

```
# Tasks Controller
def show
   @projects = Project.all
   @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
   @task = Task.find(params[:id])
   @tasks = @project.tasks.all
end

def create
   @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
   @task = @project.tasks.new(task_params)
   @task.save
   redirect_to @project
end

#Form
  <%= form_for([@project, @task]) do |f| %>
      <%= f.text_field :title %>
      <%= f.submit %>
  <% end %>
```

Is there any way to force rails to always create new tasks from this form?

Comment: Did you try `method: :post`? You missed the colon before `post` in your question.

Comment: Hi, I got excited when I realized I skipped the colon, but it still doesn't work. When I use `<%= form_for([@project, @task], method: :post) do |f| %>` I still get `<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch" />` in the HTML.

Comment: Do you have your project hosted on heroku or anywhere? The problem could be with jQuery UJs. Check your browser's console for any kind of errors or warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try assigning a new task object using the existing task's attributes. That way the form will POST rather than PATCH:

```
# Tasks Controller
def show
   @projects = Project.all
   @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
   @task = Task.find(params[:id])
   @new_task = Task.new(title: @task.title)
   @tasks = @project.tasks.all
end

# ...

#Form
<%= form_for([@project, @new_task]) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```